# How to Group By Json Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array and i want to apply group By column (key).
I have this.

```
app.groupDtData = function(data, column) {
  var generatedData=[];
  $.each(data,function(i,dt){
    // generatedData
    // if(jQuery.inArray( "John", generatedData ))
  });
}
```

i have to push it into `generatedData`  and check by `jQuery.inArray`  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't use `inArray` for that as you need an object to hold the result, not an array. Use the `in` operator to look for the property in the object.

You would get the column value from the item and then check if it exist in the result. If it doesn't exist, add a new array by that name. Add the item to the array and lastly return the result:

```
app.groupDtData = function(data, column) {
  var generatedData = {};
  $.each(data, function(i, dt) {
    var key = dt[column];
    if (!(key in generatedData)) {
      generatedData[key] = [];
    }
    generatedData[key].push(dt);
  });
  return generatedData;
};
```

Demo:

```js
function group(data, column) {
  var generatedData = {};
  $.each(data, function(i, dt) {
    var key = dt[column];
    if (!(key in generatedData)) {
      generatedData[key] = [];
    }
    generatedData[key].push(dt);
  });
  return generatedData;
}

var g = group([
  { name: 'John', grp: '1' },
  { name: 'Elsa', grp: '2' },
  { name: 'Mandy', grp: '2' },
  { name: 'Bo', grp: '1' }
], 'grp');

document.write(JSON.stringify(g));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```